# manipulate variables in a function in python

Tags: python, variables, scope

```
comp_sc = 0
game_start = False

def main():
    turn_start = input('Are you Ready to play? ').lower()
    if turn_start == 'n':
        game_start = False
        print('No one is willing to play!!!')
    if turn_start == 'y':
        game_start = True

    #while game_start == True:
    for x in range(1, 5):
        com_move(comp_sc)

def roll():
    ***


def com_move(comp_sc):
    turn_score = int(roll())
    if turn_score < 6:
        comp_sc =+ turn_score
        print(comp_sc, 'comp_sc')
    elif turn_score == 6:
        comp_sc =+ 0
        game_start = False
    return comp_sc
```

in my `com_move` function, I don't see `turn_score` (which is outputting a random number through random module) adding it in `comp_sc` variable. when I run this function - `comp_sc` is always equal to `turn_score` - instead of adding up all the 5 turn_score in it.

Thank you

Comment: Use the ``global`` keyword to write to global variables.

Comment: Use `+=` and not `=+` to add to `computer_score`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`computer_score` is a **local** variable inside the `computer_move` function. You are doing the correct thing by returning it, but then you just ignore this return value. Instead, you could assign it back to the `computer_score` variable in the calling function:

```
for x in range(1, 5):
    computer_score = computer_move(computer_score, human_score)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you write `computerscore =+ turnscore` which is setting computerscore to the positive value of turnscore, so they will always be the same.

The right way would be to write `computerscore += turnscore` which will add the turnscore to the computerscore.